# System.out.println() producing a blank error screen in all of my classes in package

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My code just stopped compiling and throwing a blank error message. After testing some things, it turns out that whenever I comment out the System.out.println lines of code in my main methods the code compiles, and whenever I have a print statement, it produces a blank error message as shown in the picture. Has anyone else experienced this problem before? I am really confused as in every class in my assignment this is happening. [Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Y7h.jpg)

Comment: Try in a different IDE. This guy had the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433576/error-message-shows-but-there-are-no-errors-in-the-code-java#comment83858660_48433576

Comment: [Eclipse shows empty error message with Java 9](//stackoverflow.com/q/45907867)